# Align two signals with different sampling rates using cross correlation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I want to align two signals that are similar but shifted using cross-correlation. While this question has been answered a few times before (see references at the bottom), this situation is slightly different and / or I was unable to get the solutions work in my application.

*The main difference is that the signals have different sampling rates and that I am inputting not just two signals, but their corresponding time vectors as well.*

I thought I would be able to solve this problem by just interpolating both datasets onto the same time line, but I could not get this to work properly.

Here's what I have tried so far.

1. Create two signals at different sampling rates, the second being shifted by 7 seconds w.r.t the first signal. They are however the same signals if not for the different sampling rate.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.signal import correlate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

dt1 = 2.4
t1 = np.arange(0,20,dt1)
y1 = np.sin(t1) + t1/10

dt2 = 1
t2 = np.arange(0,20,dt2)
y2 = np.sin(t2) + t2/10
offset_t2 = 7 # would want to recover this eventually.
t2 = t2 + offset_t2
```

2. In order to not have to deal with the issue of the different sampling rates, I interpolate the two datasets onto timelines with the same sampling rate (the coarser one).

```py
max_dt = max(dt1,dt2)
t1_resampled = np.arange(t1[0],t1[-1],max_dt)
t2_resampled = np.arange(t2[0],t2[-1],max_dt)

y1_resampled = interp1d(t1,y1)(t1_resampled)
y2_resampled = interp1d(t2,y2)(t2_resampled)
```

3. I try to use the maximum of the cross-correlation to get the shift that I need to apply but that does not yield the right result as shown in this plot.

```py
fig,axs=plt.subplots(2,1)
ax = axs[0]
ax.plot(t1,y1,"-o",label='y1')
ax.plot(t2,y2,"-o",label='y2')


xcorr = correlate(y1_resampled,y2_resampled)
argmax_index = np.argmax(xcorr)
shift = (argmax_index-(len(y2_resampled)+1))*max_dt

ax.plot(t2+shift,y2,"-o",label='y2 shifted')

ax = axs[1]
ax.plot(xcorr)
ax.scatter(argmax_index,xcorr[argmax_index],color='red')
axs[0].legend()
print(f"computed shift: {shift}\nexpected shift: {offset_t2}")
```

[image]

Clearly the blue and the green curve do not overlap and the computed shift of -4.8 does not match the offset of 7.

So I wonder if someone could help me implementing the `shift` function that I need for my example. It should return a value `delta_t` such that when plotting `(t1,y1)` and `(t2+delta_t,y2)` the signals overlap as well as possible.

It should look something like the following snippet, but I am unable to implement it.

```py
def shift(t1,y1,t2,y2)->float:
    
    # If necessary, interpolate to same sampling rate.
    # But this might not be necessary. 
    max_dt = max(dt1,dt2)
    t1_resampled = np.arange(t1[0],t1[-1],max_dt)
    t2_resampled = np.arange(t2[0],t2[-1],max_dt)

    y1_resampled = interp1d(t1,y1)(t1_resampled)
    y2_resampled = interp1d(t2,y2)(t2_resampled)
    
    
    # Do something with the cross correlation ...
    # ...
    # delta_t = ...
    
    
    return delta_t
```

**References that did not help**

[Use of pandas.shift() to align datasets based on scipy.signal.correlate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642443/use-of-pandas-shift-to-align-datasets-based-on-scipy-signal-correlate)

[Python aligning, stretching and synchronizing array data in python (signal processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085028/python-aligning-stretching-and-synchronizing-array-data-in-python-signal-proce)

[Python cross correlation - why does shifting a timeseries not change the results (lag)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484490/python-cross-correlation-why-does-shifting-a-timeseries-not-change-the-results)

Comment: I think your problem is with resampling, you are not implementing it correctly. I propose to just use `resampy` - it is just one line of code and comes with anti-aliasing filter (which you are missing as well..)

Comment: I will look into `resampy`, but In this case, even when using the same sample rates, the alignment isn't working properly so I wonder what else is going wrong.

Comment: Did you already see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492882/find-time-shift-of-two-signals-using-cross-correlation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028753/find-signal-or-phase-delay-from-cross-correlation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688715/find-time-shift-between-two-similar-waveforms

Comment: Thanks! But the first did not work, maybe because of the `delay_array` being used that doesn't translate well to my example. The second didn't have a solution for my problem and the last one differed because of different signal lengths. So far I haven't been able to translate any example into my application.

Comment: Your plot is confusing and makes it seem like your code is actually working, since by coincidence `argmax_index` is 7. Instead you should be plotting with `timescale = (np.arange(len(xcorr)) - len(y2_resampled) - 1)*max_dt`.